# How to decide which model we select

Tags: bada

This is the first application that I am going to do in Bada SDK 2.0.2. While creating the project for the first time it asked me to select model and version numbers like Wave WVGA, Wave WQVGA, and Wave WVGA. Now my questions are

1. What is the difference between these models?
2. If I select any of the model, is it possible that my app run in all other devices, that means it could support multiple screen?
3. Is selecting auto scale-ling make my app run on all screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Basically these resolutions are for devices,

```
WVGA- Wave,Wave II,Wave III
HVGA-Wave M
WQVGA-S5250,S2530,S7250
```

2.I guess this depends on your application,some devices like wave support autoscaling, Also there is a tool where it auto adjusts your app to different resolutins in Bada IDE.
3.Yes, but its better you check

Answer (score 0):

WVGA, HVGA, WQVGA - it is screen resolution.

WVGA  [480x800] - this resolution used in Wave,Wave II,Wave III
HVGA  [320x480] - this resolution used in Wave M and Wave Y
WQVGA [240x400] - this resolution used in other model(s5250, s7230, s5780...etc)

if you create form using sdk visual redactor(not XML), form must scaling to other device. For example now i create app for Wave M and I used WQVGA model for test, and form scaling normal